# useNavigate react router v6 causing the browser to throttle. using firebase auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I am trying to create authentication using firebase and react. After creating the login component and authContext I try to log in a user but every time I go to the browser I get an error in the console saying:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I haven't used any `useEffect` yet. Also the cursor looks like it is blinking. Here's the code for the login component.

```
function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: user });
            navigate("/");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="max-w-[64rem] mx-auto mt-14">
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-6 mx-auto items-center w-2/5 bg-slate-50 rounded py-4">
                <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-slate-800">
                    Login
                </h1>
                <div className="w-3/4 space-y-5">
                    <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className="flex flex-col gap-y-14">
                        <TextInput
                            label="Email address"
                            type="email"
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            disabled={loading}
                            className="px-3 py-2 bg-buttonbg hover:bg-btnhover transition-all duration-150 ease-in text-white font-medium">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have tried several solutions like adding a `useEffect` but none has worked yet.

The auth context code if you need it.

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
   currentUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("adminUser")) || null,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("adminUser", JSON.stringify(state.currentUser));
    }, [state.currentUser]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser: state.currentUser, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Mind you when I comment out the `navigate("/")` line the throttling is gone.

Comment: Is the render looping happening immediately when the app mounts/loads, or after you interact with it? Can you provide a more clear, complete, and concise set of reproduction steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: The looping happens when I open the login component. Lets say there is a user already in local storage, I can interact with the app smoothly but immediately i logout and go to the login component the looping starts. Bottom line is the looping happens after the login component is mounted not when the whole app is mounted.

Comment: If a user is logged in why does the app code allow access to the login route? I don't see anything in the `Login` component that could trigger a render loop. Perhaps I've also misunderstood what you mean by "throttling". Have you included all relevant routing and authentication code? Can you clarify what "throttling" means, and confirm the error/issue?

Comment: The browser seems to be reloading the webpage loads of times. I can't even type in the input fields in the `Login` component. I haven't faced this error before so i'm not fully aware of what is going on. But the error stack shows the problem starts at the `useNavigate` line.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I just created the sandbox and the code seems to run without any problems there.[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-lovelace-29kqh3)

Comment: Yeah, the code in the sandbox appears to be well behaved. I still don't see anything in the `Login` component that *could* trigger a render loop. I don't see any unintentional side-effect(s). Only think I can think of is something is immediately submitting the form or unconditionally calling the `handleLogin` handler somewhere. Maybe there is and it wasn't copied into your question's code snippet. Or maybe there's still more to the code you've not shared.